# waypoints.js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [waypoints.js](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/) in a project to fire an event whenever a list element becomes visible. The only problem is, nothing seems to be happening - the waypoint.reached event does not seem to be firing.

The file (waypoints.js) is being included correctly, as is jQuery, in the correct order.

You can view the (work in progress) page [here](http://smartvent.wasabi.co/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to attach the waypoint functionality to an element that doesn't exist yet.  Put `$(document).ready(function() { //your code here });` around your code and it will work.

Also, you should add the `type="javascript"` attribute to your script tags - it's not optional as far as I can remember.

Comment: Good grief. I wish I could go back and un-ask this question :P

Comment: Or, move the script block to just before the end of `body`, instead of inside `head`. It's all opinion, really, though I find it cleaner and more semantically correct to avoid littering `head` with various things like scripts.

Comment: Heh, there's always the delete function - can't say I haven't done it before ;)

Comment: @Delan - very much so, I stay away from including anything but absolutely necessary js code in the head section.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that as of HTML5 the `type` attribute for the `script` tag is officially optional. Here are the [docs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-script-element.html#the-script-element).